# Left hand limit of right hand limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I need help figuring this out

Suppose we have an increasing function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and we define a function $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the following way:
$$ g(x) := \lim_{t \to x^{+}}f(t).$$
We know that since $f$ is monotone, then the right hand limit exists and the function $g$ is well defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My question is: what can we say about $\lim_{t \to x^{-}}g(t)$ and is it true that it is equal to $\lim_{t \to x^{-}}f(t)$?

I proved that the function $g$ is right-continuous, obtaining
$$\lim_{t \to x^{+}}g(t) = g(x) = \lim_{t \to x^{+}}f(t)$$ but I’m having a hard time proving what happens for the left hand limits.
Intuitively, I’d say that the left hand limits are also equal. One can easily prove that $g(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is continuous at $x$.
Thus, the only points where $f$ and $g$ may differ are the discontinuity points of $f$ and, in particular, those for which $f(x) = lim_{t \to x^{-}}f(t)$.

Still, I don’t know if this is true and how to prove it rigorously. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\lim_{t \to x^-}g(t) $ exists and is equal to $\lim_{t \to x^-}f(t)$.

*Proof:* Set $a = \lim_{t \to x^-} f(t)$. For any given $\epsilon > 0$ exists a $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
|f(t) - a| < \epsilon \text{ for all } t \in (x- \delta, x) \, .
$$
If we fix $t \in (x- \delta, x)$ then
$$
 |f(s) - a| < \epsilon \text{ for all } s \in (t, x)
$$
and therefore, taking the right limit $s \to t^+$,
$$
 |g(t) - a| \le \epsilon \text{ for all } t \in (x- \delta, x) \, .
$$
Since $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrary, $\lim_{t \to x^-}g(t) $ exists and is equal to $a$.

*Remark:* The monotonicity of $f$ is not needed for this proof, only the existence of the left and right limit of $f(x)$ at any point.